# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'is_expression_type'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyomo

I am working on a large scale model, here is a heavily simplified version:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
import pandas as pd

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

charge_daily = pd.read_csv("input.csv")

#Range of hour
model.h = pyo.RangeSet(0,23)
#Storage Technologies
model.str = pyo.Set(initialize=["phs"])

# I need these because I do some df computation (not relevant to the issue) on the input data beforehand and a Series afterhand (instead of importing data as Series)
days=charge_daily.iloc[:,0].values
value=charge_daily.iloc[:,1].values
charge_daily = pd.Series(value, index=[days])

# Converting to hourly data. I found that dictionary are faster to build but dataframe faster to use, hence the conversion
charge = {}
for str_tec in model.str:
    for h in model.h:
        day = int(h/24)
        charge[str_tec, h] = charge_daily[day]/24
charge = pd.Series(list(charge.values()),index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(charge.keys()))

print(charge)

# What is stored at each hour
model.stored = pyo.Var(((storage, h) for storage in model.str for h in model.h), within=pyo.NonNegativeReals, initialize=0)
# What is taken from storage at each hour
model.gene = pyo.Var(((tec,h) for tec in model.str for h in model.h), within=pyo.NonNegativeReals, initialize=0)

def objective_rule(model):
    """Get constraint for the final objective function"""

    return (sum(sum(model.gene[tec, h] for h in model.h) for tec in model.str))
model.objective = pyo.Objective(rule=objective_rule)

def storing_constraint_rule(model, h, tec):
    """Get constraint on storing."""

    hPOne = h+1 if h < model.h.last() else 0
    return model.stored[tec, hPOne] == model.stored[tec, h] + charge[tec, h] - model.gene[tec,h]
model.storing_constraint = pyo.Constraint(model.h, model.str, rule=storing_constraint_rule)

opt = SolverFactory('gurobi')
results = opt.solve(model)
```

I work on an energy storage technology, which charges every hour and can produce some of the stored energy. The objective is trivial here, I oversimplified the whole model.

The input data is stored in a file like this at a daily timestep, which is converted in hourly timestep within the code.

```
day,value
0,0.39166009138686114
```

Here is the catch : the model runs perfectly fine with a `python3 my_model.py` call. However, commenting the `opt.solve` command and solving with `pyomo solve my_model.py --solver='gurobi'` results in the following error:

> ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint storing_constraint with index (0, 'phs'): AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'is_expression_type'
>
> ERROR: Constructing component 'storing_constraint' from data=None failed:
> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'is_expression_type'

First time I get this.

Any idea on why this happens and how to fix it ? I need to use a `pyomo solve` call

Digging a little bit a found that the `charge` variable is different in each case :

- running with `python3` and an opt.solve line : exactly what I want (I have several tecs)

```
phs  0     0.016319
     1     0.016319
     2     0.016319
     3     0.016319
     4     0.016319
     5     0.016319
     6     0.016319
     7     0.016319
     8     0.016319
     9     0.016319
     10    0.016319
     11    0.016319
     12    0.016319
     13    0.016319
     14    0.016319
     15    0.016319
     16    0.016319
     17    0.016319
     18    0.016319
     19    0.016319
     20    0.016319
     21    0.016319
     22    0.016319
     23    0.016319
dtype: float64
```

- running `pyomo solve` : weird stuff, not even sorted anymore

```
phs  19    0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     6     0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     15    0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     2     0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     11    0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     20    0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     7     0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     16    0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     3     0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     12    0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     21    0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     8     0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     17    0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     4     0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     13    0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     22    0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     0     0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     9     0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     18    0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     5     0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     14    0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     23    0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     1     0    0.016319
dtype: float64
     10    0    0.016319
dtype: float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that there is something goin on with `input.csv`.  Are there multiple copies of that floating around and/or are you executing the file from different parent directories or something?

The likely reason (you don't provide enough data to duplicate the problem) you are getting this is that within the constraint construction it is simplifying down to a trivial expression or something that doesn't evaluate properly.  When h=0 your expression simplifies to:

```
model.gene[tec, h] == charge[tec, h]
```

and whatever is element you have for `charge` there isn't working out.

Advice:  Print out what you are reading in from pandas in some format **before** you create the model to make sure it passes inspection.  Or, (better) ditch pandas completely here and just read in the `csv` values with `csv_reader` and avoid the pandas Series problems.